# Not able to update SRV record in route53

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

Somehow I am not able to update or delete single or adding any new with the existing SRV records in route53 and keeps on overwriting whatever I execute.

```
echo '{ "Comment": "'$COMMENT'", "Changes":[ { "Action": "UPSERT", "ResourceRecordSet": { "ResourceRecords": [ { "Value": "0 0 7000 '"$FQDN"'" } ], "Name": "'_proctest._tcp."$DNSN"'", "Type": "SRV", "TTL": 5} } ] }' | aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id "${ZONEID##*/}" --change-batch file:///dev/stdin --query '[ChangeInfo.Comment, ChangeInfo.Id, ChangeInfo.Status, ChangeInfo.SubmittedAt]' --output text
```

Is there any way to avoid this from the bash.

Answer (score 0):

> `UPSERT`: If a resource record set does not already exist, AWS creates it. If a resource set does exist, Amazon Route 53 updates it with the values in the request.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/change-resource-record-sets.html

You are asking Route 53 to change the record **set** value to this:

```
[ { "Value": "0 0 7000 '"$FQDN"'" } ]
```

It's an array of only one element.

Preserving existing values means passing the entire array of existing and new records.  The records are a "set" that is treated as an atomic unit.  You can't send an API request to modify the set in place.

Comment: okay, you mean that first I have to read and store the existing SRV record in the variable and than I have to modify whatever needed in that variable after that I have to apply all records again back to Route53 which will overwrite it. If so, I am not sure how it's going to help if i am going to run this from more than one instance at time.  Thanks for your help's!!!